# how to keep md-datepicker (angular material 2.0.0) from closing

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

user can click the icon to open the picker, I can picker.open() to open it. However, it closes as soon as I do anything (choose a day, click else where, etc). Is there a way to make it stay open?

I read that it was not possible in angularjs material1. is it possible now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a recommended solution, you could do this:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker" (click)="pickerOpened()"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

.

```
@ViewChild(MdDatepicker) datepicker

pickerOpened() {
  setTimeout(() => this.datepicker.opened = false);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/eAr7oQC0gqZAsjb3k7Sp?p=preview

Comment: why does it work? Does it trick the widget to think that it is not opened (so doesn't try to close it)?


It is sort of too effective. I can't interact with the page at all. That's why it is not provided as a built in feature.


Also it is not easy to style my stuff so that they are not covered by the calendar.

Comment: Yeah exactly, so it isn't a versatile solution, but might give you some ideas... There's an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4801) for using the calendar free from the datepicker popup, which may be what you need.

Comment: In general, I think the team is trying to avoid "disable close" features since it adds all sort of async/accessibility issues. Maybe chime in on that linked issue in my last comment with your use case. It might help it gain more traction.

Comment: when I have enough real estate, having it opened is easier to interact with, for example to change it from one day to another to see which day is best (by looking at the other day-dependent attributes on the screen). However, the current calendar is a popup and covers up other controls, and thus limits the usefulness in this scenario.

Answer (score -3):

view

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController" layout-padding>
    {{ date }}<br /> 
    <input type="date" ng-model="date" ng-click="openDatePicker()" ng-show="!datePickerOpened">
    <md-calendar class="fixed-calendar" ng-show="datePickerOpened" ng-model="date"></md-calendar>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed-calendar {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  display: block;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-calendar-scroll-mask {
  width: 340px !important;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
  width: 340px !important;
  height: 308px;
}
```

Application

```
Angular
    .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope, $timeout) {

    //Init
    $scope.datePickerOpened = false;
    $scope.date = new Date();

    //show datepicker action
    $scope.openDatePicker = function () {

        //show datepicker
        $scope.datePickerOpened = true

        //avoid date set to 1933 by async reinit date after ng-show rendering
        $timeout(function () {
             $scope.date = new Date();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: this is angular 1

Comment: you answer is for angularjs. Material2 works with angular2/4

Comment: This is an idea that it will work for material 2 as welll

Comment: you have to explain your answer than

Comment: where did you add your explanation? I don't understand angularjs and therefore your answer.